# MySQL str_to_date time conversion fails

Tags: mysql, str-to-date

I have the following statement that in other installations of MySQL appeared to work fine and return a TIME, while now returns a NULL (which, according to [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date), implies a conversion failure):

```
mysql> select STR_TO_DATE('17:54:23', '%H:%i:%s') AS test;
+------+
| test |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0,00 sec)

mysqls> show warnings;
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                       |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1411 | Incorrect datetime value: '17:54:23' for function str_to_date |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

And yet according to docs " It takes a string str and a format string format. STR_TO_DATE() returns a DATETIME value if the format string contains both date and time parts, or a DATE or TIME value if the string contains only date or time parts".
As said, used to work in previous versions, and I have people with other installations of 5.7 telling me that it works for them.

Info on the local MySQL version:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                   |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.7.20                  |
| protocol_version        | 10                      |
| slave_type_conversions  |                         |
| tls_version             | TLSv1,TLSv1.1           |
| version                 | 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 |
| version_comment         | (Ubuntu)                |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                  |
| version_compile_os      | Linux                   |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

The installation is "out of the box", Linux Mint, with no tweaking.
Anyone has a clue as to why it does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh, it just required to read the docs a bit further it seems:

"If the NO_ZERO_DATE or NO_ZERO_IN_DATE SQL mode is enabled, zero dates or part of dates are disallowed. In that case, STR_TO_DATE() returns NULL and generates a warning:"